# In select2 4.0 there isn't Italy i18n file

Tags: jquery-select2

In new select2 version Version 4.0.0 beta 2 there isn't support for Italy language in i18n folder.
I have already copy i18n/en.js file and rename in i18n/it.js but this does not work.
How can I fix it ?

Comment: you should manually load the it.js, like this: `<script src="js/i18n/it.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` after load select.js

Comment: In select2 4.0.1 there is a it.js file, so that should fix the problem.

I'm guessing that your copy trick may have worked (with incorrect translations, of course) if you had edited the file to change `e.define("select2/i18n/en", ...` to be `e.define("select2/i18n/it", ...`

Answer (score 0):

include scripts :

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/select2/dist/js/i18n/it.js') }}"></script>
```

end the execution part :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".select2").select2({language: "it"});

        // ...
    });
</script>
```